# Stop javascript "animation" onclick div

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm a beginner in javascript and I'm trying to make a very simple game. I know that my code is not the best, but i want to make it working. I want to stop function nahoru() or make it move to the other way and after it touches the bottom of the page/100%, make it repeat.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function naloud() {
            var elem = document.getElementById("krtek");
            elem.style.top = '100%';
            var eleme = document.getElementById("krtek2");
            eleme.style.top = '100%';
            var elemen = document.getElementById("krtek3");
            elemen.style.top = '100%';
        }
        var pos = 100;
        var los = 0;

        function nahoru() {
            var elemend = document.getElementById("batn");
            elemend.style.opacity = '0';

            var elem = document.getElementById("krtek");
            var id = setInterval(frame, 30);

            function frame() {
                if (pos == 0) {
                    clearInterval(id);
                    document.write('<center>GAME OVER<br>YOUR SCORE: ' + skore +
                        '<br>Press F5 for restart.')

                } else {
                    pos = pos - 1;
                    elem.style.top = pos + '%';
                }
            }
        }
        var skore = 0;

        function pric() {
            skore++;
            document.getElementById("skore").innerHTML = "Skore: " + skore;
            elem.style.top = '+100%';
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        .prvni {
            position: absolute;
            width: 10%;
            height: 110%;
            left: 10%;
            background-color: brown;
        }
        
        .druhy {
            position: absolute;
            width: 10%;
            height: 110%;
            left: 45%;
            background-color: brown;
        }
        
        .treti {
            position: absolute;
            width: 10%;
            height: 110%;
            left: 80%;
            background-color: brown;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body onload="naloud()">
    <button onclick="nahoru()" id="batn">START</button>
    <div id="skore">Skore: 0</div>
    <div id="krtek" class="prvni" onclick="pric()"></div>
    <div id="krtek2" class="druhy" onclick="pric()"></div>
    <div id="krtek3" class="treti" onclick="pric()"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Answer (score 0):

Declare id outside nahoru function,
like here

```
var pos = 100;
var los = 0;
var id = null;
```

Set interval in nahoru function,
like this (important, remove var from here)

```
id = setInterval(frame, 30);
```

Now clear interval in pric function
like this

```
function pric(elem) {
        skore++;
        clearInterval(id);
        document.getElementById("skore").innerHTML = "Skore: " + skore;
        elem.style.top = '+100%';
    }
```

Working https://jsfiddle.net/ee1bdL5k/

Comment: Thank you. I expected that I would wait for an answer for a long time, but you convinced me otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You  need declare this var outside from function, for the pric function:

```
var elem, eleme, elemen;  
function naloud() {
    elem = document.getElementById("krtek");
    elem.style.top = '100%';
    eleme = document.getElementById("krtek2");
    eleme.style.top = '100%';
    elemen = document.getElementById("krtek3");
    elemen.style.top = '100%';
}
```